# Getting munin to get totals accoss nodes

Tags: amazon-ec2, munin

Below is my config file for munin.  I am trying to do a test for summing the loads across machiches.  The nodes are showing up un munin but the total is not.  Did I leave something out?

```
[ec2-50-17-142-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com]
address 50.17.142.0
use_node_name yes

[ec2-107-20-94-67.compute-1.amazonaws.com]
address 107.20.94.67
use_node_name yes

[ec2-107-21-83-181.compute-1.amazonaws.com]
address 107.21.83.181
use_node_name yes


[compute-1.amazonaws.com;Totals]
update no
load.graph_title Total load
load.sum_load.label load
load.sum_load.special_stack  ec2-50-17-142-0=ec2-50-17-142-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com:load.load  ec2-107-20-94-67=ec2-107-20-94-67.compute-1.amazonaws.com:load.load  ec2-107-21-83-181=ec2-107-21-83-181.compute-1.amazonaws.com:load.load
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
[compute-1.amazonaws.com;Totals]  
update no  
load.graph_title Total load  
load.sum_load.label load  
load.sum_load.sum ec2-50-17-142-0=ec2-50-17-142-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com:load.load ec2-107-20-94-67=ec2-107-20-94-67.compute-1.amazonaws.com:load.load ec2-107-21-83-181=ec2-107-21-83-181.compute-1.amazonaws.com:load.load
```